# Expected URI to be a string to_sql()

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, dask, dask-to-sql

I am trying to upload a large dask dataframe to a sql server but i'm getting an error and can't see anything wrong with the connection string. I am able to connect to the DB using this connection string but I get the error when running the following:

```
import sqlalchemy as sa
import dask.dataframe as dd
from dask.diagnostics import ProgressBar
pbar = ProgressBar()
pbar.register()
#windows authentication + fast_executemany=True
to_sql_uri = sa.create_engine('mssql+pyodbc://TEST-BI/DB_TEST?driver=SQL Server?Trusted_Connection=yes', fast_executemany=True)
ddf.to_sql('test', uri=to_sql_uri, if_exists='replace', index=False)
```

> ValueError: Expected URI to be a string, got <class
> 'sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine'>.

i've tried forcing the conversion of to_sql_uri to string but still get an error.

Comment: i think you should replace the parameter ```uri``` with ```con```

Comment: `to_sql_uri.url`?

Comment: tried changing to con but TypeError: to_sql() got an unexpected keyword argument 'con'

Comment: to_sql_uri.url? not sure what you mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm sorry if the documentation is not clear enough ([docs page](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/dataframe-sql.html),  [api reference](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/dataframe-api.html#dask.dataframe.DataFrame.to_sql)). However, you did **not** pass a string in your call, you passed an engine instance, which is what the error message says.

You should do

```
ddf.to_sql('test', 
    uri='mssql+pyodbc://TEST-BI/DB_TEST?driver=SQL Server?Trusted_Connection=yes', 
    if_exists='replace', index=False)
```

Comment: But will that include the fast_executemany=True option? I didn't think it would?

Comment: to_sql does not currently pass arbitrary arguments to the create_engine function. Feel free to propose or implement this. However, passing an engine will never work, because the instances cannot be serialised.

Answer (score 0):

Just letting know that [`dask.dataframe.to_sql`](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/generated/dask.dataframe.to_sql.html) now (at least version 2023.12.1) accept `engine_kwargs` parameter ([Pull Request #8609](https://github.com/dask/dask/pull/8609)) that can be used to provide underlying SQLAlchemy Engine with arguments. So in case you want to use `dask.dataframe.to_sql` with [`fast_executemany` driver option](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/changelog/migration_13.html#support-for-pyodbc-fast-executemany), you now can do the following:

```py
ddf.to_sql('test', 
    uri='mssql+pyodbc://TEST-BI/DB_TEST?driver=SQL Server?Trusted_Connection=yes', 
    if_exists='replace', index=False, engine_kwargs={"fast_executemany": True})
```